# WinUI3 TabView XAML does not update the data binding in the view

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3

Currently working on a simple UWP App using C#, WinUI3 and XAML. Very much like the new changes Microsoft did here. However, I got stuck on some strange bindings problem that I can not make sense of. I am using as simple `ObservableCollection<ProfileTab> ProfileTabs` which should get initialized with a single tab and show in a `muxs.TabView`. I just straight followed the example in the XAML Controls Galary ( https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/f95e0a2003be53228030dcf72032fcb47b96060f/XamlControlsGallery/ControlPages/TabViewPage.xaml.cs & https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/f95e0a2003be53228030dcf72032fcb47b96060f/XamlControlsGallery/ControlPages/TabViewPage.xaml)

**XAML Code**

```
<TabView Grid.Row="1" TabItemsSource="{x:Bind ProfileTabs, Mode=OneWay}" AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddButtonClick" TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested">
  <TabView.TabItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ProfileTab">
      <muxc:TabViewItem Header="{x:Bind TabHeader}" IconSource="{x:Bind TabIconSource}" Content="{x:Bind TabContent}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabView.TabItemTemplate >
</TabView>
```

**C# Code**

```
public class ProfileTab
{
    public string TabHeader { get; set; }
    public IconSource TabIconSource { get; set; }
    public object TabContent { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ProfileTab> ProfileTabs { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitializeSampleProfile();
    }

    private void TabView_AddButtonClick(TabView sender, object args)
    {
        var profile = new SettingsProfile("");
        ProfileTabs.Add(CreateNewTab(profile));
    }

    private void TabView_TabCloseRequested(TabView sender, TabViewTabCloseRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        ProfileTabs.Remove(args.Item as ProfileTab);
    }

    private ProfileTab CreateNewTab(SettingsProfile profile)
    {
        var profileTab = new ProfileTab
        {
            TabHeader = $"{profile.PrettyName()}",
            TabIconSource = new SymbolIconSource() { Symbol = Symbol.Document },
        };

        // The content of the tab is a frame that contains a page, pass the profile as parameter
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(ProfilePage), profile);
        profileTab.TabContent = frame;

        return profileTab;
    }

    private void InitializeSampleProfile()
    {
        ProfileTabs = new ObservableCollection<ProfileTab>();

        // load sample data

        ProfileTabs.Add(CreateNewTab(defaultProfile));
    }
}
```

Now the default tab is initialized, I thought great! But whenever add or remove is clicked nothing happened. I started the Debugger, the events get triggered and the `ObservableCollection` seems indeed changing - adding and removing the displayed Tab. Now the problem is the view itself does not change - just the single default tab.

Anyone can point me to the bug or workaround? Thanks!

Comment: I have tested with WinUI 2.4.3 and it works well, we could not reproduce your problem, please share more detail about your project target min version and the WinUI version.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  - Thx for testing, appreciate the quick help and your input! I am using VS 2019 Version 16.8.1, .NET 5 SDK installed, the project is set up as a Universal Windows App with the latest WinUI3 Preview.Target version is 10.0.18362.0, target min version is 10.0.17763.0.

Comment: I tested with same environment like yours, but I could not reproduce your problem, I will share code sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/TableViewItem), please try to run it and let me know the reasult.

Comment: This one works for me, now the question is what went wrong cause I can not tell any difference in code yet.

Comment: Please share your code sample I will edit base on that.

Comment: The only thing which seems different to me is the Microsoft vs Windows namespaces for the UI.

Comment: Which namespace you have used?

Comment: And you seem to mix them aswell - xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" and using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls; using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

Comment: I used using Microsoft only.

Comment: I checked my sample I only use  `xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"`, I have not used `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` in the xaml

Comment: Not In thew XAML, but you are mixing them in the C#

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have too much time to find the problem, so I will just use your solution since it works ;) Huge thx!

Comment: Ok，and may I make answer for this question ?

Comment: Yes, please do.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested above code, it works well in my side, and I have make simple sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/TableViewItem) please check that.

And please note the `IconSource` of `TabView` is under `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` namespace, please don't use `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` `IconSource` to replace, or it will type exception.